# How do Remote Procedure Calls relate to Web Services?

Tags: web-services, terminology, rpc

So here is the question how are Remote Procedure Calls (RPC) related to Web Services?

Cheers, 
J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They both allow for interprocess communication. [XML-RPC](http://www.xmlrpc.com/) is a kind of [RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) that is even closer to web services as it allows for interoperable communication between disparate environments over the HTTP protocol.